# comparing several items in two lists with if and for loop

Tags: python, list, append, cmp

hi im a noobie to python. 
im trying to write a code for my homework that, first you're entering a number to show that how many inputs you want to enter. i have two list (p for price and q for quality) , each line of inputs includes two numbers ( the first one is price and the second one is quality) like this : 22 31

```
n = int(input())
p,q= [],[]
counter = 0
for i in range(n):
    laptopPrice,laptopQuality = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    p.append(laptopPrice) 
    q.append(laptopQuality)
```

i want to compare every items of each lists separatly that if p[0] is smaller than p[1] and q[0] is greater than q[1] the program prints " you're right " .
i wrote a code but i cant explain the if part in code .
is there any one to help and solve this homework?

Comment: Your example doesn't show the `if` block that you mentioned.

Comment: what could be the length of list? and how often you want ot print "you're right" , i mean for every pair of price and quality or single time

Comment: There is no comparison going on at all. There is no loop over your inputted numbers. This is not a good [mcve] because your problem seems to be in the comparison, not the inputting - which is the harder part of both. Hardcode two lists, play around with conditions and printing. This looks like a "here is the start, finish it providing conditions unsing a for loop ...". Did you look at a tutorial for loops? Did you look at conditions and printing? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditio

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find the laptop that has simultaneously the lowest price and the highest quality?  How do you want to handle the case where values are "good" in one category and "bad" in the other, e.g. which choice is "right" out of `[(1, 1), (9, 9)]`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

Comment: exactly as the mr.artner says i want to find the laptop that has simultaneously the lowest price and the highest quality. is there any possibilities that i put the numbers in one list like this [ price,quality,price,quality,price,quality, ...] and after that start to compare items?

Answer (score 0):

```
number_of_laptops = int(input())
list_of_prices = []
list_of_qualities = []

for i in range(0,number_of_laptops):
    inp = input()
    numbers = []
    numbers = [int(s) for s in inp.split() if s.isdigit()]
    list_of_prices.append(numbers[0])
    list_of_qualities.append(numbers[1])

def find_better_lp(number_of_laptops):

if number_of_laptops == 0:
    return print("empty list")

for i in range(0,number_of_laptops):
    for j in range(0,number_of_laptops):      
        if((list_of_prices[i] <= list_of_prices[j]) and i != j):
            if(list_of_qualities[i] >= list_of_qualities[j]):
                return print("happy irsa")

return print("poor irsa")

find_better_lp(number_of_laptops)
```